# Clicking Custom Element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click what seems to be a custom element on a webpage. I have tried various methods but I cannot get it to work.

The element is circled in this screenshot:

[image]

And can be found [here](https://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/2022-01-12-kempton/19:30/winner). The element can be accessed by clicking one of the boxes in the grid.

Here are some of the things I have tried to access it:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2S_LCT']")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ew--26832009171']")
```

Is the element inaccessible or is there a way of clicking on it?

Comment: What are the steps to reach to that web element ?

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey the script clicks on one of the boxes in the grid to bring it up. This example is from clicking a link under the Paddy Power header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get XPath of an element on website page, you can right click on the HTML element in inspector and in the menu Copy, you will be able to Copy full XPath.

[image: Copy full XPath on Chrome]

Answer (score -1):

There are basically **4 ways** to click in **Selenium**.

I will use this **xpath**

```
//input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@id,'ew--')]
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@id,'ew--')]").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@id,'ew--')]"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@id,'ew--')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@id,'ew--')]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```